# I am trying to figure out a regex in JavaScript for removing any strings before the dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for some help with Regex syntax. I tried many ways to make the syntax for this case, but nothing seems to work. Could someone help me with this?

So I have a case where I am trying to replace everything before the "." symbol in this string,

```
example_ so.myname
```

I successfully removed all the strings before the "." using this expression:

```
var removeStrBeforeDot = params.value.replace(/(\<b\>|\<nobr\>)[a-z]*\./g, "");
    removeStrBeforeDot = removeStrBeforeDot.replace(/\(.*\)\<\/b\>/g, " ");
```

But the issue with this expression is, this works when there is only letters before the dot and doesn't work when there are symbols like *, space, etc. Like for example, example* so.myname has a space and a "_" which is not working in this case. What I like to do is keep it more generic and remove any string before the "."  to be removed. Any help could be greatly appreciable.

Thanks!

Comment: http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: If there's more than one dot, do you want to match the first one or the last one?

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```js
var str = 'example_ so.myname';
var result = str.replace(/[^.]*.(.*)/g , '$1');

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id='el'></div>
```

---

Another solution : most rapid, and less expensive !

```js
    var str = 'example_ so.myname';
    var result = str.slice(str.indexOf('.')+1)
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id='el'></div>
```

Comment: I tried your regex but its keeping the dots and removing all the strings. So the result I see when I run is only dots and no strings. I was not able to open  the run code snippet too.

Comment: I've updated, just check it. it was missing '$1'. and i added a div in my snippet to see the result without the console

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It gets the position of the first dot and then collects the characters in the string from that point forward.

```
var dot = str.indexOf('.');
var afterDot = str.substr(dot+1);
```

Don't use a regex if you can do it with a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
st = 'example_ so.myname';
re = str.replace(/^.*\.+/g , '');
console.log(re)
```

Comment: Either use `\.` or `[.]`. You don't need to escape dot inside brackets, and you don't need to put a single character in brackets.

Comment: yea correct except that you will need to to this _\. escaping the dot_ because otherwise its a wild character for anything..

Comment: That's what I said, either escape it or put it in brackets, but not both.

Comment: You don't need the `+`, since `.*` will perform a greedy match. So if there's a sequence of `.` characters in the string, the wildcard will match everything  before the last one.

Comment: Depending on how you read the OPs question, it sounds like he wants to remove characters before the dot, but not the dot itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is probably the easiest way:

```js
   alert("example_ so.myname".split(/\./)[1]);
```

Comment: What is there's more than one dot? Why `/\./` instead of just `'.'`?